# Unable to extract a dynamic value from URL path in Regex

Tags: regex, jmeter

It might be a duplicate but I tried hard getting help from all other questions but still not able to extract the value. It would be great if someone can explain as well how to extract from URLs like below;

I want to extract the value "mrmuscle-daily-surface-mist-250g" but this will be dynamic and any special characters can come here too. Only way to differentiate is to get the value before /p and after the URL. Thanks in advance

```
https://my-name.com:8080/mrmuscle-daily-surface-mist-250g/p/170113
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used boundary value extraction in JMeter to extract this. But still not able to get it done by regex.

Problem is solved by a workaround.